# How to bypass eg header and its contents and html code by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I have javascript code that replaces the content of `data-src` in each `img` tag with `src`. I would like to skip, for example, header and its content because I have a slider in it that works like this script only in it turns `src` into `data-src` and thus it doesn't work for me. I would like to add the header content to the exceptions so that the script would be everywhere but not in the header and its content

```js
function czLazyload() {
  'use strict';

  j('[data-src]').each(function() {
    if (j(this).data('src') && ScrollIntoView(j(this))) {
      j(this).attr('src', j(this).data('src')).attr('srcset', j(this).attr('old')).removeAttr('data-src old').addClass('lazyloaded');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's **.not()** should help you here

```
function czLazyload() {
  'use strict';

  j('[data-src]').not('header').each(function() {
    if (j(this).data('src') && ScrollIntoView(j(this))) {
      j(this).attr('src', j(this).data('src')).attr('srcset', j(this).attr('old')).removeAttr('data-src old').addClass('lazyloaded');
    }
  });
}
```

More: https://api.jquery.com/not/